# understanding about returing two object lists by json_encode when one object list is already in json format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using ajax to get facebook comments of a post so is the following php function code returns data by json encoding to ajax call.

```
echo json_encode(array($JsonData,$arr2));
die();
```

but the content in $JsonData are already in json format as i am getting those comments data of a facebook post using server side graph api call in that php function and assigned to $JsonData at first before echo.

but on the ajax success function i am not getting data.

```
success:function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
               var comments=data[0].data;
                   alert(comments);   //shows something undefined
```

(As i was getting data this way when singly i had been returning comments data only in php function this way  echo $JsonData; and in success function comments=data.data)

So now as i must get another array $arr2 by ajax call so returning data with json_encode(array($JsonData,$arr2)) not working. as $JsonData is already in json format so doing json encoding in server side might have caused problems.

but if i juse jquery json parse as follows  jQuery.parseJSON(data[0]); then i get in my way comments=jQuery.parseJSON(data[0]).data.

considering if parseJson not works on all jquery versions, what other ways i can avoid json_encode time consuming call in server side returning code when $JsonData already is in json format and make things working in success function.FYI i used "json" as dataType in ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to decode the json first before combining with your other data:

`echo json_encode(array(json_decode($JsonData),$arr2));`

Or even construct your own json like this:

`echo '[' . $JsonData . ',' . json_encode($arr2) . ']';`

which would echo an array with 2 objects in them.

Comment: Hm i will try 2nd option soon as offline now.either way seems encode and decode can't be avoided, don't you think these functions increase process times?

Comment: Yes, it does increase process time. From your code, I guess `$arr2` is an array. Therefore, it must be encoded first. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it's array but can be a associative array.but wat about parsejson, does it supported by jquery version > 1.4

Comment: I think you're asking about client-side javascript code now.. If you set jQuery ajax `dataType` option to "json", `data` will automatically parsed to JSON inside your success function. It parsing fails, it will call the `error` callback function instead of success.